# Replace the whole string in java

Tags: java, android

I have an array of string which contains list of sensors available in a smartphone.
In this array for each element I want if there is a match, replace the whole string.

For example:

```
sensor[1] = "iEnemoEngine orientation sensor";
```

I want if `sensor[1]` contains the word "orientation", replace the whole string "iEnemoEngine orientation sensor" with "orientation"

what should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (sensor[1].contains("orientation")) {
    sensor[1] = "orientation";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String orient = "orientation";

if(sensor[1].contains(orient)) sensor[1] = orient;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "iEnemoEngine orientation sensor";
String checkReplaceStr = "orientation";
if(str.contains(checkReplaceStr)){
    str = checkReplaceStr;
}
```

This should be done to each element in your `String` array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 String pattern= "orientation";
 for (int i=0; i<stringArray.length; i++){
   String str = stringArray[i];
   if (str.contains (pattern)){

     str = pattern;
     stringArray[i] = str;
    }
}
```